# Is there a way to write and i/else statement within document.write?

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement, document.write

I'm trying to make a text randomizer, something that will create new sentences given certain words and where to place them. I've created arrays of nouns, verbs, amounts, etc. The problem is, I need it to be able to give different amounts of certain nouns (eg. one apple, two bananas), and I need it to match the amount to the singular or plural version of the word. I can't have it say, `"one apples"`, or `"two banana"`. I'm wondering the best way to do this. I thought about using an if/else statement but am not sure that's possible within `document.write`. I have a lot of places I would need to do this within a longer sentence, so I'm trying to keep from writing a million different arrays.

```js
var amount = ["zero", "one", "two"]; 
var fruit = ["apple", "banana", "orange", "grape"]; 

var rand1 = [Math.floor ( Math.random() * amount.length )]; 
var rand2 = [Math.floor ( Math.random() * fruit.length )]; 

document.write("I have" + " " + amount[rand1] + fruit[rand2] + ".");
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the conditional operator. If the random amount is `one`, don't add an `s`, otherwise add an `s`:

```js
var amount = ["zero", "one", "two"];
var fruit = ["apple", "banana", "orange", "grape"];

var rand1 = [Math.floor(Math.random() * amount.length)];
var rand2 = [Math.floor(Math.random() * fruit.length)];

document.write("I have" + " " + amount[rand1] + ' ' + fruit[rand2] + (amount[rand1] === 'one' ? '' : 's') + ".");
```

Might be more readable using template literals:

```js
var amount = ["zero", "one", "two"];
var fruit = ["apple", "banana", "orange", "grape"];

var rand1 = [Math.floor(Math.random() * amount.length)];
var rand2 = [Math.floor(Math.random() * fruit.length)];

document.write(`I have ${amount[rand1]} ${fruit[rand2]}${amount[rand1] === 'one' ? '' : 's'}.`);
```

The expression

```
amount[rand1] === 'one' ? '' : 's'
```

means: if the expression `amount[rand1]` evaluates to `one`, the conditional expression as a whole evaluates to `''`, otherwise the whole conditional expression evaluates to `''`. It's a more concise version of `if`/`else` when you need something to evaluate to one value or another.

Also note that `document.write` is rarely a good idea - if you want to show data to the user, consider inserting text into an element or using `console.log` or something like that. (See [Why is document.write considered a "bad practice"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/802854/why-is-document-write-considered-a-bad-practice)

Answer (score 0):

The answer from @CertainPerformance is very good - but keep in mind that the plural is not always just an added "s" - take "raspberry" / "raspberries" as example.

I usualy tend to add both versions to the array and choose which one to take according to the amount, something like this:

```js
var amount = ["zero", "one", "two"];
var fruit = [
 ["apple","apples"],
 ["banana","bananas"],
 ["orange","oranges"],
 ["grape","grapes"],
 ["raspberry","raspberries"]
];

var rand1 = [Math.floor(Math.random() * amount.length)];
var rand2 = [Math.floor(Math.random() * fruit.length)];

document.write(`I have ${amount[rand1]} ${fruit[rand2][amount[rand1] === 'one' ? 0 : 1]}.`);
```